# Is it possible to create a PortletRequest manually?

Tags: java, request, liferay, portlet

i want to create a PortletRequest for a Liferay Portal 5.2.3. I can't get programmatically a PortletRequest at this point in my environment. Can I create a dummyrequest with some informations? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technical answer is "yes, of course". On the other hand, the implied answer is "why would you want to?". The big question is, what data that you'd expect in the portletrequest will you have available?

You just mention "at *this* point in my environment", without specifying what *this* is. In general, if at a certain location a portletrequest is not available, you're either in the wrong layer of the application or in the wrong part of the lifecycle. Remember: The Portlet API is located on the UI layer and should not be known in your business layer. You typically pass values from the Portlet layer (e.g. portletrequest) into the businesslayer - without passing the full object.

The only place where it would make remotely sense to artificially create a request object is a test case implementation, where you can make up what you want to find in the request. Even there it's debatable if you do too much work creating such an object in order to test an extremely narrow part of the operation at hand, but still: That's the only idea that I have that could make sense. (Not to say that there are no others, but you'd have to give good reasons for it if you object)

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly. My environment is a customized liferaylogin where some information are shared with an external ldap. My goal is to sync both systems. (ldap and liferay db)

Edit: Enter -.-'
Normally I would get the logged user from liferay from the portletrequest with PortalUtil.getUser(request). Didn't thought about another solution for my problem, like UserLocalServiceUtil.getUserByScreenName(companyId, screenName).

Comment: Syncing Liferay with LDAP sounds a lot like the stock Liferay feature if you interface with an external LDAP server (judged on that single sentence, you might do more than the stock feature does, but consider to go for the built-in for maintenance reasons: You'll have to maintain less custom code this way. But then - good that you found a solution that works for you. Rewriting that certainly takes time. Consider changing for the next maintenance (upgrade?) cycle you do.